# What is firefoxprofile counterpart for Chrome browser?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using firefoxprofile to handle the window based file download popup.

```
public static FirefoxProfile FFprofile() {


        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                "application/vnd.ms-excel,application/msword, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream");
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
        profile.setPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);

        return profile;
    }
```

and I call the firefoxdriver by using the following :

```
Webdriver browserdriver=new FirefoxDriver(FFprofile());
```

This is working fine in case of firefox browser.

Is there any way to have similar profile to handle popup in case of chrome?

Answer (score 0):

can you try using ChromeOptions and see,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
options.addArguments("--browser.download.folderList=2");
-------
-------
chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

hopefully the same should work out.